# How to make Dreamweaver AP Div Show/hide functions work in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, dreamweaver

I created a page using Dreamweaver and fireworks that uses one AP Div as a button to show and hide two other AP Divs using JavaScript. However, the AP divs are relatively places. It all works fine in google chrome and safari but it doesn't work at all in IE 9. I suspect it's an issue with the JavaScript and IE9. I am new to this, and I know my site is built in a weird way. All help is appreciated.

I also tried using this tutorial:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/dhtml/a/aa101507.htm  (Shows and Hides divs with a link)

where the a div is a link, to make it work, but it didn't fix it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What happens in IE9? Sorry I'm on a mac, which makes it difficult to see the problem :)

Comment: Nothing. You click the "i" and the text boxes don't switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've scrapped your code, not because it's bad but because I dont understand it :P, I've used something different, this may mean that you have to re-write some code on your page. What my code does it replaces the content with-in the div instead of hiding/showing between 2 divs... Below is a link to a jsfiddle, try running it in IE9 and see if that works.

http://jsfiddle.net/hSMk3/

If it doesn't work tell me in the comment section thingy below :)

Comment: Thanks you! That's exactly what I need! I got it to work in IE9 and now all I have to do is tweak it.